# JS : loading image

Tags: addeventlistener

I'm trying to make an event listener to say images have been loaded.
I have the code below, but I have this error : "myImage.addEventListener is not a function"

```
const myImage = document.querySelectorAll("img");

myImage.addEventListener("load", function(){
    console.log("OK");
});
```

Could you tell me what is the problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myImage = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
```

You were selecting your image. But it returns an array.

From the docs:

> Returns a non-live NodeList of all elements descended from the element
>   on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of CSS
>   selectors. (The base element itself is not included, even if it
>   matches.)

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const myImage = $("img");

myImage.on("load", function(){

   console.log("OK");

});
```

Comment: I have the same problem "myImage.on is not a function"